# require_once() adds line-break at the beginning of file

Tags: php, mysql, newline, require-once

This is part of my code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('../engine/class.admin.php');
$admin = new Admin;
 //some code
if(!isset($_COOKIE['logged']) && !isset($_SESSION['logged']) ) {
    //some code
} else {
    require_once('header.php');
}
ob_flush();
```

When i'm trying to load this page, PHP adds a CRLF tags at the beginning of page. Everything looks good, when i remove both require_once() tags, it's impossible to run this code without these files. Where i need to start finding solution of my problem?

Comment: What is the contents of `../engine/class.admin.php`?

Comment: check where's that `CRLF`. Maybe before the `<?php` tags of some of the file included.

Comment: you can always dismiss the trailing `?>` in your php-scripts. That's often a source for unwanted linefeeds

Comment: class.admin.php contains a class and multi-line comment. There is also no php closing tag

Comment: just a guess: try changing `new Admin;` to `new Admin();`  (only because I never saw that without brackets)

Comment: brackets doesn't changed anything. CRLF still appears at the output.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I have changed encoding of my IDE to UTF-8 Without BOM and this problem disappeared. I've also to overwrite any included files to work with the same encoding.